# Where is a Load Balancer located region or AZ? (for Architecture Diagrams)

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-elb

When drawing Architecture Diagrams, where should the Load Balancer be? I think inside VPC but outside an Availability Zone correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Load balancer spins up additional nodes (aka Load balancer nodes) in different VPC.
- This VPC is not visible to users (see ELB VPC). This is from AWS Re:Invent. This is how ELB placement was explained.

[image]

- So in arch. diagram it should stay out from your VPC, may be at the boundary (for the sake of simplicity

Comment: From the diagram, it looks like its inside VPC?

Comment: Yes, AWS users do not have visibility to this VPC.

Comment: Ah I understand what you mean, its inside AWS own VPC and not the user's VPCs

Answer (score 2):

AWS Load Balancer is created outside of AZ, but you need to assign AZ to it to distribute traffic.

Read [How Elastic Load Balancing Works](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html):

> When you enable an Availability Zone for your load balancer, Elastic
>   Load Balancing creates a load balancer node in the Availability Zone.

Usually on the diagrams Load balancer placed inside AZ like on the diagram from [Internet-Facing Classic Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-internet-facing-load-balancers.html) AWS Documentation page.

[image]